# Whats the difference between one terminal power source vs. two terminals power source in circuit simulators?

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, vcc

I found a step down voltage regulator circuit online and tried to simulate it and noticed that it runs when I use the one terminal power source and it doesn't run when I use the two terminal power source! Can anyone explain why is that!

Here is the circuit where it regulates 40 volts into 5 volts using one terminal power source:

[image]

Here is the same circuit using two terminal power source:

[image]

Comment: You've connected the two-terminal power source wrong.

Comment: The longer line indicates the more positive voltage.

Comment: But also, you should connect it between ground and th collector node, if you want the same behavior as your first circuit

Comment: You did not use gnd on your supply http://tinyurl.com/y5ptef6j

Comment: Learn to adopt conventions for Bat + high and ground low with inputs left to right. This is what the ROTW uses.

Comment: That was a lot of help! Thank you all gentlemen!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the top schematic, the power/battery positive is connected to both the transistor collector and the 10k resistor. The negative is implied to be ground and thus connected to the 257 ohm resistor and the diode.

In the bottom schematic, instead, you have battery positive connected only to the collector! The negative, instead of being connected to ground, is connected to the 10k resistor. The resistor and the collector are no longer connected together. In other words, you’ve placed the battery wrong, in series between the resistor and transistor.

Comment: now I see what was my mistake! Thanks a lot!